# No picture or sound from SNES, newer-ish tv?

Tags: technical-issues, snes

I just bought a SNES on eBay and I was pretty disappointed to open the box and see that the port for the power cable  is busted (missing the actual port, just had two wires left) anyway, according to other websites I should still be able to make it work. I have the red light shinnjng on the Nintendo console, and have tried putting in different games and resetting, etc. Nothing seems to work. On my tv channel 3 and 4 just show up as black screens with the message "no input". The video and hdmi channels are black too, no sound either. So you think it is because of the port or is the actual Nintendo console dead? I will probably return it but I was super stoked to get this so I thought I better give it a last ditch effort.. I will try to upload some picks of how I have everything set up.

Comment: According to the tag, I'm guessing this is about a NES. But if we assume the letters got all mixed up, it could also be a SNES (Super NES). Which is it?

Comment: Sorry! I meant SNES

Comment: Dumb question, but what have you plugged into the back of your TV?  Is it the Coax cable or did you use a component cable or something?  There is a good chance that the person who broke the power cable port broke the others, too.  If it is the coax cable, you will probably need to do some setup on your TV, too.

Comment: It's the coax cable I think, the one that looks like an hexagon with a little prong sticking out of the center?

Comment: Do you think it's worth buying a new set of av cables to see if it works? I just don't want to waste the money if there's no point...

Comment: Probably better to return it, and buy one of those retro consoles that can play NES and SNES games instead.

Comment: Ooh I didn't even know that was possible thanks :)

Comment: "There are TVs being made now that no longer support analog NTSC RF input" - "Is it possible there's a menu option to tell the tuner to look for NTSC instead of ATSC?" –[atariage.com](http://atariage.com/forums/topic/174354-just-got-a-flat-screen-tv/)

Answer (score 5):

It takes a LOT to kill off a SNES, so I wouldn't give up on it until it's been tested thoroughly. If the red light goes on, it probably works.

First of all, I wouldn't ever use coaxial/RF signal to hook up a SNES. First of all, that results in the worst possible image quality you can get, second of all there's a good chance you'll have problems making it work on modern TVs - as long as you're using that, it could be anything.

First, I'd try getting my hands on a regular AV (audio/video) cable for the SNES, those are the ones that look like this:
http://www.tegames.co.uk/media/raw/6FT-SNES-AV-Cable-for-N64-Gamecube-VF401-.jpg

These provide the type of image called "composite", which is still not the best quality, but easiest to test, as they always work! It's the exact same cable used for both SNES, N64 and GameCube, so they should be very easy to come by - if you don't already have one, you can probably borrow one from someone, for testing. These are plugged into one of the TV's AV ports (which I would guess is what you're describing as the "video channels" on your TV itself)

Answer (score -2):

SNES/NES/Genesis/possibly N64 use AV cables. Yellow/Red/White, or some other combination of 3 colors. Connect those to your TV-if you don't have that connection type available, you will need an adapter available at RadioShack or some other electronic stores. Set your TV input to AV-and it should give you the picture/sound when matched.